# Why can't I change this label with this button?

Tags: c#, forms, button, label

```
using System;  
using System.Drawing;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  
namespace Test  
{  
    class mainWindow : Form  
    {  
        public mainWindow()  
        {  
            Label firstLabel = new label();  
            firstLabel.Text = "Hello";  
            this.Controls.Add(firstLabel);  
            Button firstButton = new Button();  
            firstButton.Text = "Click me";  
            firstButton.Click += firstButton_Click;  
            firstbutton.Left = 100;  
            this.Controls.Add(firstButton);  
        }  
        void firstButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            firstlabel.Text = "Goodbye";  
        }  
    }  
    class XxX  
    {  
        static void Main()  
        {  
            mainWindow form = new mainWindow();  
            Application.Run(form);  
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please format your code using the `{ }` button in the future.

Comment: Your code won't compile. Even if you fix the capitalization of some variables, you'll need to declare `firstlabel` as a member of your class.

Comment: Since you are creating Control object Dynamically at runtime, make sure u specify co - ordinates of the control on the form

Answer (score 3):

Because `firstLabel` is a local variable scoped to the `mainWindow` constructor. You could make `firstLabel` a private member of the `mainWindow` class:

```
class mainWindow : Form  
{  
    private Label firstLabel;
    public mainWindow()  
    {  
        firstLabel = new Label();  
        firstLabel.Text = "Hello";  
        this.Controls.Add(firstLabel);  
        Button firstButton = new Button();  
        firstButton.Text = "Click me";  
        firstButton.Click += firstButton_Click;  
        firstbutton.Left = 100;  
        this.Controls.Add(firstButton);  
    }  
    void firstButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        firstLabel.Text = "Goodbye";  
    }  
}
```

Additionally, most classes are conventionally `PascalCased` and not `camelCased` (i.e. `class MainWindow` instead of `mainWindow`).

Comment: I made firstLabel a private member of the class, but now I'm getting an error when I press the button:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MyFirstScratchApp.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Did you post all of your code? The only thing that could be null on the button click is `firstLabel`, which we've instantiated inside of the `mainWindow` constructor.

Comment: I didn't post all of the code, I got frustrated and rage quitted, then re wrote just a small part for the question, I was following a tutorial on the microsoft website that show how to make a maths game, but I wanted to do it from scratch rather than clicking and dragging stuff from the toolbox, there was alot of code...

Comment: @user1924485: Gotcha. I would try setting a breakpoint inside of the click handler and step through each line. That way you should easily be able to tell what variable contains a `null` reference.

Comment: I just checked my IDE, it compiles, so I thought there were no errors, but it says my label is never assigned to, and will always have it's default value null. Also I'm very new to C#, I don't know what a breakpoint is...

Comment: Hmm... When I paste the code in a new project it seems to work fine. Is the `mainWindow` constructor (`public mainWindow() { ... }`) being called correctly?

Comment: When I paste the code into my IDE, I get the same error, I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 and .NET 4.5 if that makes any difference

Comment: @user1924485: You could try declaring and initializing the private member: `private Label firstLabel = new Label()`. But the code should work--I'm using the same setup actually.

Comment: It works now, I declared and initialized the private member and removed it from being initialized inside the mainWindow contructor. Thanks, you're the best!

Comment: Also I just found out why it wasn't working, I had `private Label firstLabel;` outside the contructor, and `Label firstLabel = new Label();` inside it, I was declaring? it twice

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Test
{
    class mainWindow : Form
    {
        // since u need to access the control, u need to keep that control at global level
        private Button firstButton = null;
        private Label firstLabel = null;
        public mainWindow()
        {
            firstLabel = new Label();
            firstLabel.Text = "Hello";
            Controls.Add(firstLabel);
            Button firstButton = new Button();
            firstButton.Text = "Click me";
            firstButton.Click += firstButton_Click;
            firstButton.Left = 100;
            Controls.Add(firstButton);
        }
        void firstButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // now since the variable is global u can access it and change the title
            firstLabel.Text = "Goodbye";
        }
    }
    static class XxX
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            mainWindow form = new mainWindow();
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another important distinction is that global variables *don't exist* in C#. And the part about memory isn't right. *Every variable* associates a variable name with a memory location.

Comment: well i meant to say that it must be Global for that Class!

Comment: As in, *not* necessarily accessible by any function comprising the program?

Comment: if they are at Class Scope level rather then Function Scope variable

Comment: above all, global variable can be defined in c# within a public static class using internal/public modifier